# How can I get an even checker texture on that kind of cone object?

Tags: texturing, uv

How can I get the checker texture to display evenly(in square shapes), when dealing with kind of cone object. P.s. I tried UV unwrap, but for some reason it didn't really help. Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Hi :). You connected generated coordinates, not your UV map ;)

Comment: I think you'll have to UV unwrap it to get it just the way you want. When I say UV Unwrap, there are multiple types, like normal unwrap, or smart uv project, project from view, etc. You'll have to use a method, unwrap it, and then go in and tweak it manually, to get it just the way you want it. Usually I go with "Unwrap" after adding seams, then go in and tweak to get it to the way I want

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  If my answer below didn't answer your question then some more detail could be helpful, such as a screenshot of your cone's UV map and an example of what you mean by “checker texture to display evenly (in square shapes)”.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

With nods to Jachym Michal's and Aswin's comments above, given this (or similar) UV map:

[image]

An effect like what you've described can be achieved by this material:

[image]

Please note (pink arrows) that the Texture Coordinate node's output must be UV to use the object's UV Map, and the Checker Texture node's Scale must be a power of 2 (... 8, 16, 32 ...) to wrap around the cone evenly.

[image]